# Trying to compile simple wxWidgets c++ app

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets

I have this code from this page:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html

I just copied the code from below to get an idea on how to start with this library. I got the latest code version form github and by running this 
`./configure && make && make install` everything seemed to have worked fine.

Now this is my compiler (I am using OSX 10.11 default compiler):

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

For some reason when I run this, 
`g++ main.cpp` `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` `-std=c++11`

I get this error:

```
main.cpp:5:21: error: expected class name
class MyApp: public wxApp
                    ^
main.cpp:10:23: error: unknown class name 'wxFrame'; did you mean 'MyFrame'?
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
                      ^~~~~~~
                      MyFrame
main.cpp:10:7: note: 'MyFrame' declared here
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
      ^
main.cpp:10:23: error: base class has incomplete type
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:7: note: definition of 'MyFrame' is not complete until the closing '}'
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
      ^
main.cpp:13:42: error: unknown type name 'wxPoint'
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
                                         ^
main.cpp:13:62: error: unknown type name 'wxSize'
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
                                                             ^
main.cpp:15:18: error: unknown type name 'wxCommandEvent'
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
                 ^
main.cpp:16:17: error: unknown type name 'wxCommandEvent'
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
                ^
main.cpp:17:18: error: unknown type name 'wxCommandEvent'
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
                 ^
main.cpp:18:5: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
    ^
main.cpp:24:30: error: unknown type name 'wxFrame'
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
                             ^
main.cpp:25:5: error: expected function body after function declarator
    EVT_MENU(ID_Hello,   MyFrame::OnHello)
    ^
main.cpp:32:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wxPoint'
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( "Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
                                                 ^
main.cpp:32:67: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wxSize'
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( "Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
                                                                  ^
main.cpp:33:12: error: no member named 'Show' in 'MyFrame'
    frame->Show( true );
    ~~~~~  ^
main.cpp:36:47: error: unknown type name 'wxPoint'
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
                                              ^
main.cpp:36:67: error: unknown type name 'wxSize'
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
                                                                  ^
main.cpp:39:5: error: unknown type name 'wxMenu'; did you mean 'NSMenu'?
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    ^~~~~~
    NSMenu
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3088:28: note: 'NSMenu' declared here
DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS(NSMenu);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3059:16: note: expanded from macro 'DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS'
typedef struct klass *WX_##klass
               ^
main.cpp:39:28: error: unknown type name 'wxMenu'; did you mean 'NSMenu'?
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
                           ^~~~~~
                           NSMenu
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3088:28: note: 'NSMenu' declared here
DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS(NSMenu);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3059:16: note: expanded from macro 'DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS'
typedef struct klass *WX_##klass
               ^
main.cpp:39:28: error: allocation of incomplete type 'NSMenu'
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
                           ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3088:28: note: forward declaration of 'NSMenu'
DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS(NSMenu);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:3059:16: note: expanded from macro 'DECLARE_WXCOCOA_OBJC_CLASS'
typedef struct klass *WX_##klass
               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Why is it looking for `MyFrame` and does not use the `wxFrame`?
How can I make this run ?

PS: I have removed these lines:

```
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
```

If I do use them then I get this:

```
In file included from main.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/wx.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/event.h:21:
In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/cursor.h:14:
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/gdiobj.h:89:5: warning: 'GetClassInfo' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Winconsistent-missing-override]
    wxDECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS(wxGDIObject);
    ^
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/rtti.h:142:5: note: expanded from macro 'wxDECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS'
    wxDECLARE_ABSTRACT_CLASS(name);
```

...and goes on.. in a huge stacktrace...

Any help please?

Comment: You need the wx.h header so the wxApp class gets declared, that's the reason for the first error. When you do include it can you show more of the errors/warnings? If it's super long possibly paste into https://gist.github.com/ or another paste service.

Comment: This is what I do not get. Why will I need the header file? I already inistalled the wxWidget library on my system.

Comment: You need the #include statement to read the class declaration into your source file. Look up some C or C++ tutorials to see how the preprocessor makes this work.